# Can you use an averb with avoir mal à?

Tags: grammaire, usage, verbes, adverbes

In French, is it possible to use adverbs and qualifiers with avoir mal and are they positioned correctly after the verb 'j'ai'?

Exemple:

J'ai surtout mal à la tête = I have a headache in particular.

J'ai parfois mal au dos = I sometimes have backache.

J'ai très mal aux yeux = I have very sore eyes.

J'ai assez mal au cou = I have quite a sore neck.

Merci

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

All these phrases are correct. In French, it is possible to say "j'ai surtout .." or " j'ai parfois mal à ..." or "j'ai très mal ..." or "j'ai assez mal ... It is a French speaking writer who is now speaking !